# A sequence avoiding 3-term power progressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Rankin<sup>1</sup> studied sequences of integers that avoid 3-term geometric progressions,
$(a, a c, a c^2)$,
e.g.,
$$\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, \ldots \} \;$$
So, $18$ is excluded because $(2,6,18)=(2,2 {\cdot} 3, 2 {\cdot} 3^2)$ forms a geometric progression. He showed that the 
[asymptotic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of that greedy sequence exceeds $0.71$.

I wondered about sequences that avoid 3-term *power progressions*,
$(a, a c, a c^k)$, where $c\ge 2$ and $k\ge 2$ are natural numbers.
Here I start again with $(1,2)$ and continue to add the first number that
avoids all 3-term power progressions:
$$\{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26, 29, 
30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, \ldots \}\;.$$
For example, $8$ is excluded because $(1,2,8)=(1,1{\cdot} 2, 1 {\cdot} 2^3)$
is a power sequence.
Much later, $945$ is excluded because $(35,105,945)=(35, 35{\cdot} 3, 35 {\cdot} 3^3)$.

> ***Q***. What is the asymptotic density of the above greedy sequence
>   that avoids all 3-term power progressions?

---

[image: PowerAvoidingDensity]

---

The density appears to be about $0.63$, up to $644$ terms ending in $1021$.
Note that the square-free integers have density $6/\pi^2 \approx 0.61$.
My sequence is square-free, cube-free, etc., because $(1, c, c^k)$ is a 
power progression.

---

<sup>1</sup>R. Rankin. "Sets of integers containing not more than a given number of terms in arithmetical progression."
*Proc. Roy. Soc. Edinburgh Sect. A*. 65 (1961).
Cited by Nathan McNew in poster, "Avoiding Geometric Progressions in the Integers." ([PDF download](https://math.dartmouth.edu/graduate-students/works/2013-14/McNew-GradPosterSession.pdf).)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Masacroso: What is the asymptotic density. My simulations are hardly definitive. Or bounds on the density.